# Scoping with Dart's final keyword

Tags: scope, dart, final

The following code compiles and runs fine:

```
void testFinal() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final x = i + 1;
    print(x);
  }
}
```

So it appears that the final annotation "re-applies" each time through the loop. This seems at variance with the motivation for final, which (I type-infer) is to allow the compiler better to guarantee certain code transformations. Are we to consider the loop as a bunch of unrolled, separate scopes?

Answer (score 4):

All blocks have their own scope:

```dart
void main() {
  if (true)
  {
    final x = 0;
  }
  final x = 10; //ok
}
```

won't work:

```dart
void main() {
  final x = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x = i + 1; //NoSuchMethodError: cannot assign to final variable 'x'
    print(x);
  }
}
```

but this one will:

```dart
void main() {
  final x = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final x = i + 1; //ok again
    print(x);
  }
}
```

Because each iteration you say "i want a new final x"

They are block level finals and it's a new declaration each time. Since those are finals, not statics - it's expected behavior. At least, they can help you avoid some mistakes and provide code annotation that basically says: "won't change".

Answer (score 3):

In short: yes.

Each block is its own scope. Every time you execute a block, it creates new instances of the variables in the block.

A "final" variable can only be initialized once, but every time you "execute" the declaration, a new unmodifiable variable is created. It doesn't matter whether the block is just a simple nested block, or it is a loop body, or even a function body.

```dart
main() {
  foo(1); 
  foo(2);
}

void foo(final parameter) {
  final local = parameter * 2;
  for (final i in [1, 2]) {
    final block1 = local + i;
    {
       final block2 = local + i * 2;
       print(parameter * local * block1 * block2);
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, all the final variables take more than one value during the life time of the program. Each time a final declaration is executed, the variable is introduced into the scope with a value, and when the block/scope is exited, the variable ceases to exist again.

The `for(final i in ...)` is handled specially, so the `i` variable is also created once for each loop iteration.